# PHPExcel different styles in the same cell

Tags: phpexcel

Hello: I'm using PHPExcel in a project and need to apply different styles in the same cell.

This is an example: [example image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3iMq_0cgOrSldiOHVoVmFRTFE/view?usp=sharing)

as I can do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Rich Text. This is [documented](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#add-rich-text-to-a-cell) and there is an example provided in `05featuredemo.inc.php`

There is even a helper utility in the 1.8.1 release that can be used to convert a block of html markup to a PHPExcel Rich Text Run, and example `42richText.php` demonstrating how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I could use Rich Text but have the same problem: Excel5 writer seems broken when adding many RichText cells. Reference link https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/284    as I can solve it?

Comment: Using Rich Text is the only way of applying different styles to text in the same cell.... how many is "many"?

Comment: for example, this report is good and has 7 rows http://aysys010.com.ar/report_ok.xls  but this report that has 44 rows fails to open and lose formatting  http://aysys010.com.ar/report_error.xls

Comment: in the last example, if the  Rich Text  to remove any of the columns the file opens without error